# How to mock http:request-config that has oauth2

Tags: mule, functional-testing

I'm writing functional test and having difficulty mocking `http:request-config` with oauth2. It failed at requesting for token. I tried moving the config to a separate file and create a different config in `src/test/resources` and include only the test config when testing. Now it complains about "name must be unique" - how do I get around this?

Comment: Hi there how are you doing to mock the config top level element?

Comment: that's actually my question... right now I just create a different config file without the oauth2 `src/test/resources` for testing.

Comment: have a look at the mule-module-oauth : https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.x/modules/oauth/src/test/java/org/mule/module/oauth2/internal - source code, there are test cases for the three supported types of oauth.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your getConfigFiles() override does not include the configuration file that contains the original .  This means it will need to be in a separate file from the one containing the flow you are testing.

Another method is to use a mock HTTP server such as [sham-http](https://github.com/shamsoftware/sham-http).

Comment: yep, I only include the mocked config file in `getConfigFiles` however Anypoint studio complains about unique name even when not testing. I'll look at sham-http.

Comment: Yes, Anypoint Studio will complain if the extra config is in src/main/app when you run the application.  Make sure it is in src/test/resources, and be sure to remove it from mule-deploy.properties to get around that.  When running tests, are you still getting the error?

Comment: even if I put it in `src/test/resources`, it still complains about unique name. It's not in `mule-deploy.properties` either. Running test gives no errors but the Studio gives me the warning if I want to run the app. So I just rename it to `.txt` file instead.

Comment: @BPm can you detail the solution you arrived at? You're replacing the HTTP global config when running the tests?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test Mule application you can use MUnit:
http://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/MUnit

It will allow you to mock message processors. 
Now, config elements are top level elements. Those can not be mock.

I would suggest you take a look to documentation to see if the tool fit your needs. 
HTH